# Syntax error: File to import not found or unreadable: compass/css3

Tags: ruby, css, sass, gruntjs, compass-sass

I already have a `config.rb` in the root with the following:

```
# Require any additional compass plugins here.

# Set this to the root of your project when deployed:
http_path = "/"
css_dir = "css"
sass_dir = "sass"
images_dir = "images"
javascripts_dir = "js"

# generated_images_dir = "/images/"
http_generated_images_path = "../images"
```

I'm using Gruntfile.js and I made it work to compile but I get this error once file is compiled:

```
Running "sass:dist" (sass) task
Syntax error: File to import not found or unreadable: compass/css3.
              Load paths:
                /Users/DanielRamirez/Sites/020
                /Users/DanielRamirez/Sites/020/sass
        on line 86 of sass/_base.scss
        from line 7 of sass/style.scss
  Use --trace for backtrace.
```

I recently had to restore my hard drive so maybe some things are missing. I reinstalled compass using:

```
gem install compass
```

I have a macbook so I do not need to install ruby as it comes in the package if I understand well.

What do I have to do to make this work?

Comment: What is on line 86 of `sass/_base.scss`? Seems like the error is indicating an issue there.

Comment: If you run it via Compass, rather than with Grunt, does it work?

Comment: @jakerella In line 86 I have the first compass import. Concretely compass/css3. If I would take that out it would give me error in the next compass import, so there is an issue with the compass itself.

Comment: So it looks like it's trying to access the `css3` mixin at those locations (`/Users/...`) are they there? If not, do you need to install them? Or maybe change the `PATH` environment variable to correctly point to your gem install location?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you try to compile your styles by sass task (sass:dist), but use compass mixin as well.

What kind of sass compiler do you use?

There is a good decision. You should try to switch to the grunt-contrib-sass (https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-contrib-sass), that have internal support for compass.( set options compass:true)

Comment: I want to use grunt from now on for my compiling. I already have declared grunt-contrib-sass in my Gruntfile.js. HOw can I insert this option? After that I will check if that solves my problems ;)

Comment: actually grunt do not compile sass, it is only wrapper for compass and sass gems. Can you post your gruntfile in the question and then i can update my anwser more rightly

Answer (score 0):

Recently had the same issue when I moved to a file structure for my SASS (partials/_name.scss) and then moved my site to a DEVELOPMENT environment. Error went away after I opened the files, made a small change (space bar) and saved. I am sure there is a more elegant way but this allowed me to move on.

Answer (score 0):

With the current version of " grunt-contrib-sass " you have to set compass option to true in your sass task i.e:

```
 sass: {
        dis: {
            options: {
                style: 'compressed',
                compass: true
            },
            files: {
                'stylesheets/screen.css' : 'sass/screen.scss'
            }
      }
    },
```

Check [Documantion](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-contrib-sass)